# returning a value from a function in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function in jquery. my function returns a value but when i checked the returned value, I got a 'NAN' what could be the problem:

```
[CODE]

 var vax = ('#textbox1').val();

 var newVal = calculateMB(vax,11,3.1);
 alert(newVal);

 function calculateMB(num,charge,fixed)
 {
   if(num>50)
   var e = num - 50;
    var new_e = e * charge;
    new_var = new_e / 20;

     return (new_var + fixed);


   }
 [/CODE]
```

Comment: Try `alert(vax)` right after you assign the value to `vax`. You may not be getting what you think you're getting.

Comment: Your function only returns a value if `num>50`. That's a problem.

Comment: @JonathanM: No, it always returns a value. The `if` only relates to the line that follows it. (Very, very hard to read the code with the indentation all messed up like that.)

Comment: @ henry: Note that this has nothing whatsoever to do with jQuery. Your function is just a JavaScript function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is because the number being read from the text box is a string. Try `var vax = Number(('#textbox1').val());`

Answer (score 3):

You aren't always assigning a value to `e`, but you're using it in calcuation. Here's that code indented properly:

```
function calculateMB(num,charge,fixed)
{
    if(num>50)
        var e = num - 50;

    var new_e = e * charge;
    new_var = new_e / 20;
    return (new_var + fixed);
}
```

When `num` is `<=` 50, `e` never gets a value (and so stays with the default `undefined`), so `e * charge` is `NaN` and `NaN` propagates through the rest of the calculation.

You probably want:

```
function calculateMB(num,charge,fixed)
{
    var e, new_e, new_var;

    e = (num > 50) ? num - 50 : num;
    new_e = e * charge;
    new_var = new_e / 20;
    return new_var + fixed;
}
```

Changes there:

1. I put all `var` statements at the top, because [that's where they really are](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/poor-misunderstood-var.html).
2. I declared `new_var`, which you hadn't declared at all, falling prey to [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html).
3. I ensured that `e` always gets assigned a value. I guessed you wanted `e` to be `num` when `num <= 50`, but adjust that as appropriate.
4. I indented the code consistently. Doing things like consistent code indentation help you avoid bugs, and help others understand your code. *Strongly* recommend it.

Comment: @brightgarden: Yes, they are. (I didn't say they weren't.) `e` will still be `undefined`. It's only the `var` part, not the assignment part, that's hoisted. E.g., `var e = num - 50;` becomes `var e;`, which is hoisted, and `e = num - 50;`, which is not.

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
 return (Number(new_var + fixed));
```

It casts your variable as a number. Also ensure that the parameters being passed to calculateMB are in fact numbers.